# Fragment not letting me use setOnClickListener

Tags: android

I am trying to use setOnClickListener on my fragment but it is not letting me and saying I need to implement onClick into onClickListener, which I have... Can someone please explain what I did wrong?

Fragment code:

```
package layout;


import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


import test.testing.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    ImageView event1 = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gray_circle1);
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        LinearLayout event = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ev1);
        event.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                event1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorcircle);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

Fragment XML:

```
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ev1"
        android:onClick="activate"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/gray_circle1"
            android:background="@drawable/graycircle"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Event 1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Event 2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/graycircle"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Event 1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Event 3 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/graycircle"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Event 1"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `onClickListener` needs to start with a capital `O` - `new OnClickListener() ...`.

Comment: Don't write just this (new onClickListener()

      instead of that write (new View.onClickListener()

Comment: Why implement OnClickListener? You never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing following thing wrong:

```
event.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                event1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorcircle);
            }
        });
```

instead of this you should do this:

```
event.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and override the onClick method in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    event1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorcircle);
}
```

Comment: @beardedbeast yes both are same but if we are already implementing the OnClickListener interface than we should use it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @shridutt_kothari's answer, you can also do the following

```
event.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              event1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorcircle);
         }
    });
```

Keep in mind that using this solution does not require your fragment class to implement `View.OnClickListener`